# Connection not closed relating to the datareader

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to check if a user name exists; and if not add to the database; however it keeps giving this error: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string number = txtDriverNumber.Text;
        string name = txtDriver.Text;




        txtDriverNumber.Text = "";
        txtDriver.Text = "";
        string query = "INSERT INTO PP_TruckDrivers VALUES(@CUSTNMBR,@CUSTNAME, @telephone)";
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM PP_TruckDrivers WHERE CUSTNAME = @CUSTNAME ";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CUSTNAME", txtDriver.Text);
                command.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CUSTNMBR", number);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CUSTNAME", name);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", "");
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            con.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Driver Name already exist!');window.location='AddTruckDriver.aspx';</script>");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        this.BindFormView();
    }
```

Comment: You've got two `con.Open();` statements.

Comment: But I remove one and then it give an error that the datareader isn't close

Comment: ok but i'm not seeing where it wasn't close

Comment: So isn't there another way

Comment: All this can be done in one call, you can check if records exists, then do the insert...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ; can you show me where I went wrong please

Comment: `if exists ( 
            select 1 from PP_TruckDrivers where CUSTNAME = @CUSTNAME
          )
begin
  INSERT INTO PP_TruckDrivers VALUES(@CUSTNMBR,@CUSTNAME, @telephone)
end` all you really need to do is see if the record exist, if so do the insert.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what you want to do here? If a record doesn't exists I would assume you would want to insert a record, you example is different? If a record does exist, I would assume you would update that record...

Comment: Sorry the first comment syntax should be `IF NOT EXISTS(`... I was going off your current code in question...

Answer (score 3):

Your code is badly written because it runs a statement (sends requests) per results obtained from another query to the database. In a commercial system that simply causes an overhead. You can instead go with a cleaner SQL solution. I have provided a very small example below:

```
MERGE [dbo].[PP_TruckDrivers] AS Target
USING (VALUES (@CUSTNMBR,@CUSTNAME, @telephone)) AS Source (CustNmbr,CustName,Telephone)
ON Target.CustName = Source.CustName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (CustNmbr,CustName,Telephone) 
    VALUES (Source.CustNmbr,Source.CustName,Source.Telephone);
```

> What is a Merge Statement?

Imagine you have a Target table in/from which you may want to add, update, or delete records based on the content of another data set/table. Consider the following figure

[image]

Using the `MERGE` statement you can simply conduct pattern matching, similar to when you `JOIN` two tables while being able to apply all add, update, and delete statements on your target table. The following example shows you how to do this:

```
MERGE sales.category t 
    USING sales.category_staging s
ON (s.category_id = t.category_id)
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET 
        t.category_name = s.category_name,
        t.amount = s.amount
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT (category_id, category_name, amount)
         VALUES (s.category_id, s.category_name, s.amount)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    THEN DELETE;
```

[More information is available here](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-merge/)

Comment: @madreflection: I agree with you, but sometimes it's just the matter of personal preference. Some people like a C# approach and some are fine with SQL features.

Comment: TBH, the answer is vague, there's no explanation as where the OP went wrong in code, how does this *merge* statement work, will it fix the problem? Even if OP uses this, it wont work in their current solution; just some constructive feedback is all.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: If you read the first two lines of the question you will see that the guy the trying to add a record when a key is not already present. But his code is of low performance. I made it clear why the code is badly designed and I proposed a standard SQL solution.

Comment: @madreflection: I believe that if you just post the final solution, the OP will copy and paste it and will never learn. I am against that concept. I made the example short but syntactically clear just to add a little challenge on purpose.

Comment: @Transcendent I did read it, I agree with the code not being up to par, but there's no details to support your answer, adding more would benefit anyone as to how and why this solution would work.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: That is something I cannot disagree with. More information is always good. Ok I will add more information to my post :)

Comment: @madreflection: SO is more of a place for exchanging philosophies rather than a place for instant flawless answers. We talked, and I enjoyed talking to you :)

Comment: I totally agree. Right back atcha.